# Loop and comparing each element of array?

Tags: php

I am trying to compare each element from two array `$min` and `$max`

```
$test = false;
$min = array(2,3,3,55,556);
$max = array(22,32,4,56,557);
foreach($min as $key=>$val){
    foreach($max as $k=>$v){
      if($val >= $v){
        $test=true;
        break;
      }
  }
}


if($test){
  echo "A NOT GREATER THAN or EQUAL B";
}else{
  echo "YOU CAN SAVE NOW";
}
```

What I am wrong?because I got the message here

```
  A NOT GREATER THAN or EQUAL B
```

thanks

Comment: I'm guessing what you're trying to do is see if every element in the first array, is >= it's equivalent element in the second array? Is this true?

Comment: yes,it's equivalent element in the second array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing **every** value from $min with **every** value from $max (until you hit a value of $min that is greater than a value in $max), and 55 from $min is greater than 22 from $max, so $test will be set to true.

Are you simply trying to compare corresponding $min and $max values?

```
$test = false;
$min = array(2,3,3,55,556);
$max = array(22,32,4,56,557);
foreach($min as $key=>$val){
   if($val >= $max[$key]){
     $test=true;
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Lol, literally exact same code/comment like 2 mins apart.  Well played :-P

Answer (score 1):

Well, 55 and 556 from the $min array are greater than 22,23,4,56 from the $max array.  Are you trying to just compare the matching items?

If so then your code should look like this:

```
foreach($min as $key=>$val){
   if($val >= $max[$key]){
       $test=true;
       break;
   }       
}
```

Comment: It is the same code @Mark.,both the same idea ,thanks @Alexandru.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "break 2" to break both foreach. With "break" (or "break 1") you only stop the nested foreach. But Mark is right, the loop itself is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is of the condition u have given there, the loop is stopping when the 556 compare starts with 22, immediately the loop is break and so u r getting that message.